# Creating Java application but whenever I run on eclipse it slow down my system.why?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am Creating an Application in core Java Language. I have almost completed but I have notice that whenever I run this application in Eclipse  after 3-4 times run.My system gets too slow I have tried in other systems too.This application also effect those system too.please give  me some suggestions what should I do?

Comment: You could try installing [ProcessLasso](http://bitsum.com), it helps give your foreground applications more CPU and memory resources and is like Task Manager on steroids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means your application doesn't terminate. Check how many processes Eclipse is currently running in the `Debug` perspective. When your application ends, you will see `<terminated>` in front of the process entry in the "Debug" view.

If your application is still running, Eclipse will start a new process but the running application will eat CPU and memory. If your computer starts to swap, it will become (very) slow.

Also you might have given Eclipse too much memory. Check with the task manager of your OS how much memory you have and how much Eclipse uses.

Comment: thanks aaron sir. I cheked in Debug view and my application was not properly terminated. I didnt used System.exit method when  application
was terminated